# 'Geographer' Vs 'geographer'

Tags: capitalization

I am finalising my personal statement for applying to uni, and I have this sentence:

> I enjoy following geopolitical issues in the news as these issues have
>   a significant impact on our livelihoods, and I firmly believe that
>   being ‘in the know’ is one of the key aspects of being a Geographer.

I cannot decide whether I should capitalize 'Geographer' or not.

Should I be using 'Geographer' or 'geographer'?

Comment: Why do you want to capitalise it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it should not be capitalized.

Comment: Please give a good explanation for you answer. While this does answer the surface question it doesn't tackle the underlying problem.

Comment: In my opinion writing 'being a geographer' looks wrong when compared to 'being a Geographer'.

Comment: @cybermonkey does 'being a journalist' or 'being a teacher' look wrong to you? 'Being a Geographer' would be right if for example you wanted to be part of a band called "The Geographers". Geographer is not a name (in your case), it is a job title.

Comment: See Melanie Smits' answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be capitalized. This is because in English, only proper names are capitalized. This includes names for countries, areas, people, and so on but not for jobs or fields of study.

Like @skymninge said, the sentence is exactly similar to "being a teacher" or "being a programmer" or "being a scientist". There are a few exceptions, but this is the rule. While it can look wrong to you, especially if you believe being a geographer is very cool and important (and as such warrants a capital letter), personal opinion does not come into this. The person from the university that reviews your statement will see it as a spelling error!